# Bind SelectedItem in a ListBox to CommandParameter in a ContextMenu

Tags: wpf, binding, contextmenu, datatemplate, observablecollection

Although this question is very similar to others posted, it has a few twist! I have an **ObservableCollection** of items in a **ListBox** and use a **DataTemplate** to display some of the collection members. However, I have a **ContextMenu** defined so I can execute **DelegateCommands** defined in my ViewModel using the **Command** parameter.

All my Bindings are working up to here, except that I need to provide an argument for the Command in the ViewModel using CommandParameter of the item selected in the ListBox so that the command knows which item to act upon. But this is not possible because I changed the ContextMenu DataContext so I can get at the DelegateCommands in my ViewModel.

I get the following error: 
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=instrumentListView'. BindingExpression:Path=SelectedItem;

The Command in the ViewModel is called as I desire, but its argument is always null.

I have also tried to Bind to items inside the collection, but they are not visible because I had to switch my DataContext.

The following is abbreviated XAML file:

```
            <ListBox x:Name="instrumentListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Instruments}" >              
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                       <StackPanel x:Name="instrumentStackPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="30" UseLayoutRounding="True" Tag="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}">                            
                        <Image Source="{Binding InstrumentIcon}" Margin="0,0,10,0"></Image>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Instrument}"></Label>
                        <StackPanel.ContextMenu >
                            <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                                <MenuItem Header="Add Instrument" Command="{Binding Path=AddInstrumentToTest}" CommandParameter="{Binding Instrument}"/>
                                <MenuItem Header="Remove Instrument" Command="{Binding Path=RemoveInstrumentFromTest}" CommandParameter="{Binding Instrument}"/>
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                        </StackPanel>                            
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Here is a copy of my ViewModel:

```
     public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public DelegateCommand<string> AddInstrumentToTest { get; set; }
        public DelegateCommand<string> RemoveInstrumentFromTest { get; set; }
        private ObservableCollection<IInstrument> instruments = new ObservableCollection<IInstrument>();

        public ViewModel()
        {
            this.AddInstrumentToTest = new DelegateCommand<string >(this.OnaddInstrumentToTest, this.canAddInstrument);
            this.RemoveInstrumentFromTest = new DelegateCommand<string >(this.OnremoveInstrumentFromTest, this.canRemoveInstrument);      
        }

        public ObservableCollection<IInstrument> Instruments
        {
            ...
        }

        public void OnaddInstrumentToTest(string inst) {...}
        public void OnremoveInstrumentFromTest(string inst) {...}
        public bool canRemoveInstrument(string inst) {...}
        public bool canAddInstrument(string inst) {...}

        ...
}
```

And here is the IInstrument interface:

```
        public interface IInstrument
        {        
            string Model {get;set;}       
            string SerialNumber {get;set;}    
            InstrumentCommInterface.InstrumentInterface InstrumentComm {get;set;} 
            InstrumentClassification.InstrumentClass InstrumentClass {get;set;} 
            string FirmwareVersion {get;set;}  
            string Address {get;set;}
            string Port {get;set;}
            Lazy<IInstrumentFactory, IInstrumentPlugInMetaData> PlugInType {get;set;}
            string Instrument {get;set;}
            BitmapImage InstrumentIcon {get;set;}
            bool SelectedForTest {get;set;}
            ObservableCollection<string> Channels {get;set;}        
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would retain the `DataContext` and tunnel through the context menu tag.

```
<!-- Keep complete ListBox, allows acces of selected item and higher up DataContext -->
<StackPanel Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}">
```

```
<ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
             Tag="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

So now the `DataContext` is still your item, if you need the selected item use:

```xml
Tag.SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}
```

Comment: Hi H.B., unfortunately this does not work. As soon as just the StackPanel Tag is changed, the ViewModel binding breaks for the Commands.

Comment: Forgive me for my ignorance, but I have tried to modify your answer to no avail. What I ended up doing is using the View code behind to detect which element was selected, and then tell the ViewModel  what item was selected from there. This most certainly is not completely MVVM compliant, but is working. I would most appreciate if you could elaborate more on your solution, which seems like it would work (most elegantly might I add).